# How to call function in ReactJS in a callback within the same component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function within the component and at the same time I am using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) button to trigger display a modal. Here's the snippet:

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          error: null,
          isLoaded: false,
          table_type: 'default',
          date_time : null,
          data: [],
          header : null
      };
      this.toogleBtnTbl = this.props.toogleBtnTbl.bind(this);
      this.showModal = this.props.showModal.bind(this);
    }
```

I cant call the function `this.showModal` inside the button of Datatables because `this` refers to the Datatables in this case. My question is how to call `this.showModal` inside the `action` property?

```
buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'View in Graph',
                    action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {  
                        this.showModal();//not working undefined
                    }
                },
```

Comment: `const show = this.Modal();` then call `show()`

Comment: Where would I put that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change to arrow funcion

```
action: ( e, dt, node, config ) => {  
   this.showModal();
}
```

Comment: Ahh ok, care to explain this? The suggestion of @Omar also works by assigning it in a variable.

Comment: in arrow function you can direct call "this". instead of doing like var self = this and call self.showModal()

Comment: How come that its calling the component's `this.showModal()` function and not the `this` inside it?

Comment: You can readmore at http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html#sec_traditional-functions-bad-non-methods

Answer (score 0):

Never used DataTables but I think you just need an anonymous immediately executed function to capture "this" and store it in a closure:

```
buttons: [
            {
                text: 'View in Graph',
                action: (function(component){
                    return function ( e, dt, node, config ) {  
                        component.showModal();
                    };
                })(this);
            },
```

action is being set to a function which is immediately called storing 'this' inside it's own little lexical environment where the returned function will always have access to it.  Let me know if this works.